# How to Configure Babel, Webpack, and Corejs Properly to ensure browser compatability

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, babel-polyfill, core-js

## Background

I am desperately trying to configure Babel to compile my application to make it backwards compatible based on the target list of browsers I define.

Here is my current configuration:

**babel.config.json**

```
{
    "presets": [
        [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            {
                "corejs": 3,
                "useBuiltIns": "usage",
                "targets": {
                    "browsers": [
                        "> 1%",
                        "last 2 versions",
                        "ie >= 8"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
        [
            "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
            {
                "regenerator": true
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

In Webpack configuration:

```
{
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader'
    }
}
```

I have tried numerous things but everything I try results in certain browser errors...

## The Error(s) - and what I have tried...

With `modules` set to `false`, I get the following errors:

- **Chrome**: `Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'`
- **IE 11**: `Assignment to read-only properties is not allowed in strict mode`

With `modules` set to `commonjs`, I get the following errors:

- **IE8**: `Expected Identifier` (a lot of them)

To attempt to fix the above, I then removed the `exclude` from the Webpack rule, but this resulted in a compilation error:

`TypeError: $ is not a function`

## My Question

Quite simply, what am I doing wrong? Are there limitations to Babel's power? Should I just use `commonjs` and accept that it doesn't work in IE8?

I am hesitant to use `commonjs` as I would rather my ECMAScript is not all converted to CommonJS, but I will accept this if there is no other solution.

NOTE: The purpose of this is to show a pretty error to those on ancient browsers, and as such, I need it to be compatible with browsers such as IE8/9

Comment: Maybe just add "modules": "commonjs" to "@babel/preset-env" can fix your problem